# WIX installer, include different merge modules depending on platform

Tags: wix, setupapi

I'm writing an an application with a WIX installer. The application is requires a driver (which I also wrote), and this is installed via a merge module included in the main WIX installer project.

Different platforms require a different driver variant, and as far as I can tell, they require a different installer package, as I can't include diffxapp_x64 and diffxapp_x86 in the same installer.

So, I've got one main installer, and three merge modules (for x86, x64 and ia64). Can I use the target platform setting to conditionally include the correct merge module variant in the main installer project, spitting out three packages?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Use [WiX preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm).

When you launch build of your installer, set a WiX preprocessor variable and select different merge modules depending on the value of the variable using conditional statements.